# I am not able to Iterate the Data in a webtable using selenium webdriver

Tags: java, selenium, selenium-webdriver

```
List <WebElement> rnum = dr.findElements(By.xpath("//*[@id='leftcontainer']/table/tbody/tr"));
        for(int i=1;i<rnum.size();i++){

            List <WebElement> rowcells = dr.findElements(By.xpath("//*[@id='leftcontainer']/table/tbody/tr[rnum]/td"));

            for(int cnum=0;cnum<rowcells.size();cnum++){
                System.out.println(rowcells.get(cnum).getText());

            }

        }
```

when i ran this script it is throwing error

I tried it two times, but it's not working

> Exception in thread "main"
>   org.openqa.selenium.remote.UnreachableBrowserException: Error
>   communicating with the remote browser. It may have died. Build info:
>   version: '2.51.0', revision: '1af067d', time: '2016-02-05 19:11:55'
>   System info: host: 'ULTP_374', ip: '192.168.111.89', os.name: 'Windows
>   7', os.arch: 'amd64', os.version: '6.1', java.version: '1.7.0_75'
>   Driver info: driver.version: RemoteWebDriver Session ID:
>   03c1856b-d233-403b-98fc-c765f056aa42 Capabilities [{platform=WINDOWS,
>   acceptSslCerts=true, javascriptEnabled=true, cssSelectorsEnabled=true,
>   databaseEnabled=true, browserName=firefox, handlesAlerts=true,
>   nativeEvents=false, webStorageEnabled=true, rotatable=false,
>   locationContextEnabled=true, applicationCacheEnabled=true,
>   takesScreenshot=true, version=45.0.1}]    at
>   org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver.execute(RemoteWebDriver.java:665)
>     at
>   org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver.findElements(RemoteWebDriver.java:388)
>     at
>   org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver.findElementsByXPath(RemoteWebDriver.java:504)
>     at org.openqa.selenium.By$ByXPath.findElements(By.java:356)     at
>   org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver.findElements(RemoteWebDriver.java:351)

Comment: hope this post helps.. http://sqa.stackexchange.com/questions/8029/how-to-iterate-a-list-of-webelements-and-print-the-values-one-by-one-to-perform

Answer (score 0):

Issue seems to be that your server cannot communicate with the web browser:
Exception in thread "main" org.openqa.selenium.remote.UnreachableBrowserException: Error communicating with the remote browser. It may have died.

Looks like there is an active issue created for it:
https://github.com/seleniumhq/selenium-google-code-issue-archive/issues/4319

Answer (score 0):

Here's the answer for your webtable

```
List <WebElement> rnum = 
    dr.findElements(By.xpath("//*[@id='leftcontainer']/table/tbody/tr"));

for(int i=0; i<rnum.size(); i++){

    List <WebElement> rowcells = dr.findElements(By.xpath("//*[@id='leftcontainer']/table/tbody/tr[i]/td"));

    for(int cnum=0;cnum<rowcells.size();cnum++){
            System.out.println(rowcells.get(cnum).getText());
    }
}
```

The unreachable browser exception is for different reason. Your browser is not launched successfully.